# How to discover In-App Purchase price in the WP8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, in-app-purchase, winrt-xaml

Is there any way to discover in-app purchase price before navigating to confirmation of in-app purchase? I want to place price in my app in the custom interface. And I want to get price dynamically through Windows Phone Store or In-App Purchase API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 try
{
    //StoreManager mySM = new StoreManager();
    ListingInformation li = await Store.CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();

    foreach (string key in li.ProductListings.Keys)
    {
        ProductListing pListing = li.ProductListings[key];
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(key);

        string status = Store.CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses[key].IsActive ? "Purchased" : pListing.FormattedPrice;

        string imageLink = string.Empty;

        picItems.Add(
            new ProductItem {
                imgLink = key.Equals("molostickerdummy") ? "/Res/41.png" : "/Res/18.png",
                Name = pListing.Name,
                Status = status,
                key = key,
                BuyNowButtonVisible = Store.CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses[key].IsActive ? System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed : System.Windows.Visibility.Visible
            }
        );
    }

    pics.ItemsSource = picItems;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
```